# PHP substring and strange icon on rendered html

Tags: php, string, substring

I really dont know why on cyrillic font, substring replace some characters with "?"

My Code

```
$string1 = get_the_content();
$string = strip_tags($string1);
$stringcutted = substr($string,0,150);
$replacement = "...";
$final = substr($stringcutted, 0, -3).$replacement;
```

And look how it is rendered on html

[image: strange icon1]
[image: strange icon2]

Any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because PHP's string functions are based on strings of bytes; they have no knowledge of character encoding.  So in something like UTF-8, where a character can take up more than one byte, it doesn't work the way you'd want it to:

```
<?php 
 $x = 'Подмосковные вечера';
 print(strlen($x)."\n");        # 37, not 19
 print(substr($x,0,1)."\n");    # �, not П
 print(substr($x,0,2)."\n");    # П, not По
?>
```

Look at the [multibyte string functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php) if you want to manipulate non-ASCII text.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check out character encoding. Basically, you have a string encoded in one format, and you're ouptuting it in another format.

For international stuff (and it looks like you are doing that) then I'd use UTF-8:
 - In your HTML file add  in the head (near the top)
 - In your PHP, make sure you're handling all strings as UTF-8
 - If you also have a database, make sure the database, the tables and and fields are all configured as UTF-8 (warning: making this change may corrupt exising data without import / export!).
 - If you are reading template files with special characters, also make sure those are UTF-8. (If no special characters, then normal AscII will do)

That's the simple answer. There's lots to read about character encoding - just Google it.

(Alternative solution, use ASCII, but convert everything to web-friendly character codes. But that's trickier to get all the codes right, especially if handling user input.)

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually define the charset. Use mb_substr(). It should help.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php